# MagnificationGesture and RotationGesture SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, gesture

How i can use gestures on one view. I want use `MagnificationGesture()` and `RotationGesture()`, but if i use both gesture in one time works only one (who was initialization firstly). Maybe there is a single gesture?

Comment: Look up simultaneous gestures. There are many tutorials out there.

Comment: yep, its work. Thanks a lot!